# Deploy into my mobile device or deploy to my mobile device?

Tags: grammar

I'm worried that "deploy into" may be wrong, but for some reason it sounds more idiomatic to me than "deploy to", specifically in this sentence:

> I'm going to **deploy** my apk **into** mobile device.

**Whereas**

> I'm going to **deploy** my apk **to** mobile device.

The latter sounds weird to me.

Which one is correct? Or are both wrong?

Any explanation is genuinely appreciated!

Comment: Use "deploy to"; the other way is the one that's weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *transitive* verb "[***Deploy***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deploy)" itself has the meaning "into" in it:

> Move (troops or equipment) ***into*** position for military action:
>   'Once the strategic lift deploys Army forces ***to*** where they are
>   required, tactical logistics moves to the forefront.'
>
> Bring ***into*** effective action: small states can often deploy
>   resources more freely

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

The following Ngram Viewer shows the big difference in their usages.

[image]

As @Robusto also suggested in the comment, it is better to use "to" instead of "into" as using "deploy something into" sounds like using "into" twice in a sentence.

Comment: I think I should stop reading letters written during the American civil war, Thanks for the chart and explanation

Answer (score 3):

To **deploy into** means to assume (or be caused to assume) a particular formation.

**The infantry should deploy into three columns.**

To **deploy to** means to go or to be dispatched to a particular theater of military operations or place of action.

**The third battalion has deployed to Europe.**

**The software has been deployed to the server.**

The verbs can be used in passive constructions as well, e.g. be deployed into, be deployed to.

There is also a transitive sense that takes a direct object, meaning "to put into action"

**Remember to deploy your parachute.**